# What's the difference between reporting and analysis tools in BI sofwares

Tags: reporting, analysis, business-intelligence, pentaho

Im' working on a project where I have to use Pentaho. There are lots of tools included (or that can be include) in this solution.

I don't really see the difference between the reporting part (here PRD pentaho report designer) and the analysis part (pentaho analyzer or saiku).
For me, with both tools we can see what's in my DW and do more or less complicate reports about those data. Am i right or did I understand nothing?

thks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pentaho Reporting (PR) and Analysis tool are two different things. PR is **static** report, you can create it using sql. Analysis Tool report(AT) such as saiku, jpivot, or stpivot is **dynamic** . You must create it using MDX. By using AT, we can create analysis report dynamically according to the dimension we want.